# list indices must be integers, not str 6

Tags: python, python-3.x, record

I am very new to python and am really struggling to find a solution to this issue.

I just don't understand why I need to include only integers in my list when I though they are supposed to support multiple data types.

I've got a very simple field entry system for an account registration and I just can't add the items into a list.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've have included my code and the message I receive.

```
useraccounts = {}
group = []



forename = input('Forename: ')
surname = input('Surname: ')
DOB = input('DOB: ')
stu_class = input('Class: ')

group['forename'] = forename
group['surname'] = surname
group['dob'] = DOB
group['class'] = stu_class

group.append(user accounts)
```

This is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/admin/Documents/Homework/Computing/testing/testing.py", line 11, in <module>
    group['forename'] = forename
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`group` is a list, it cannot take string indices. It looks like you wanted to use a dictionary instead:

```
useraccounts = []
group = {}

group['forename'] = forename
group['surname'] = surname
group['dob'] = DOB
group['class'] = stu_class

useraccounts.append(group)
```

Note that you probably wanted `useraccounts` to be the list here; your code tried to call `.append()` on the `group` object..

or inline the keys and values directly into the dictionary definition:

```
useraccounts.append({
    'forename': forename,
    'surname': surname,
    'dob']: DOB,
    'class': stu_class})
```

Comment: That's great. Thanks a lot for the fast response guys

Comment: `useraccounts` is a dictionary so it has no append method. I ahve a feeling the OP thought that `group.append(useraccounts)` would add `group` to `useraccounts`

Comment: Fine by me, the rest of us need rep too @MartijnPieters ;)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a `dictionary`:

```
group = {}

group['forename'] = forename
group['surname'] = surname
group['dob'] = DOB
group['class'] = stu_class
```

In  your original code `useraccounts` stays an empty `dict` that you just append to the list. If you wanted to add `group` to `useraccounts`:

```
useraccounts['key'] = group
```

Comment: And now `group.append()` will fail.

Comment: That's great. Thanks a lot for the fast response guys

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want `group` to be a `dict`, and `useraccounts` to be a `list`. You have them backwards, as well as the append:

```
useraccounts = []   # <-- list
group = {}          # <-- dict

forename = input('Forename: ')
surname = input('Surname: ')
DOB = input('DOB: ')
stu_class = input('Class: ')

group['forename'] = forename
group['surname'] = surname
group['dob'] = DOB
group['class'] = stu_class

useraccounts.append(group)   # <-- reversed. this will append group to useraccounts
```

As written, you were trying to append `useraccuonts`, an empty list, to `group`, a `dict` which has no `append` method